# What is wrong with this ST_CONTAINS statement PostGIS - Find point in polygon

Tags: sql, ruby, gis, postgis

I'm trying the following:

`Event.where('ST_Contains(?,ST_SetSRID(location, 4326)::geography)', search_polygon::geography)`

add getting the error

> *** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `geography' for

but without that (::geography) I get a message telling me to cast, what do I do?

> HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You
>   might need to add explicit type casts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use [ST_Contains](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Contains.html) on geography types, but that function only works on geometry types.

If you are OK with the *intersects* spatial relation (see [DE-9IM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM)), then use [ST_Intersects(geography, geography)](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Intersects.html).

Comment: yep! that makes more sense